# Помогите с простой версткой

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Помогите, пожалуйста, с версткой:

https://jsfiddle.net/AlexSYS/0mtqk3dk/

```
.Center {
   border:1px solid orange;
   margin-top:118px;
   height: 100%;
   position:relative;
}
```

Почему у блока Center высота равна 100% высоты всего окна, а не родителя?

Comment: Всё нормально отображается https://jsfiddle.net/0mtqk3dk/1/

Comment: да, но вы поставили жестко высоту в 200px, а мне нужно чтобы Center занимал всю высоту Center-wrp

Comment: Я поставил 200px для блока `center-wrp`. Проблемы не вижу. У вас `center-wrp` высота 100% (высота окна). `center` занимает всю  `center-wrp`. Если я не прав, то установите для `center` `{position:absolute,top:0;bottom:0}`

Comment: я, видимо, чего-то не понимаю... вернее теперь я понял что height:100% для center и center-wrp - одна и та же - высота окна. Тогда другой вопрос - как center заставить быть ниже top, при этом при всем, должно заниматься все окно?

Comment: У вас родительский блок растянут на всю высоту окна, и конечно же его дочерний элемент (center) будет на всю высоту родительского и в высоту всего окна

Comment: пока писал - вы мне написали, но я уже дописал вопрос

Comment: Вам нужно, что бы center не выходил за границы окна?

Comment: именно так!!!!!

Comment: Держи: https://jsfiddle.net/0mtqk3dk/3/

Comment: @Yuri А можно перенести ответ из комментария?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, ну он не сказал, что это именно то что он хотел. И это не совсем ответ

Comment: @Yuri Всё равно ответ должен быть ответом, а не комментарием. Я лично вижу, что он подходит как ответ.

Comment: Yuri помог, это именно то, что мне нужно было

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вас, то в вашем классе Top также укажите значение элемента position как relative.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <style>
  body {
 margin: 0;
 height:100%;
 background: green;
 background-size: cover;
}

html {
height:100%;
}

.page-wrp {
 height:100%;
 min-height: 768px;
 position: relative;
 border:1px solid blue;
 }
.Top {
 position: relative;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 min-width: 100%;
 background: red;
 height: 118px;
}
.Center-wrp {
 position: relative;
 border:1px dotted red;
 height: 100%;
}
.Center {
 border:1px solid orange;
 margin-top:118px;
 height: 100%;
 position:relative;
}
</style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="page-wrp">
    <div class="Top">top</div>
    <div class="Center-wrp">
        <div class="Center">center</div>
    </div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```